# Build a File Monitoring System

Tags: c, filesystems, file-monitoring

I have just started programming and would like to implement a file monitoring system from scratch in C.

I have used the Watch Service API in java but I would like to learn how to build one from scratch. I would really appreciate some assistance and guidance.

Thanks.

Comment: It is operating system specific. If on Linux, see [inotify(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/inotify.7.html).

Comment: ..or on Windows, https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365465%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: 'I have just started programming and would like to implement a file monitoring system' - could you not find something easier?  IME, file monitoring requires high-priority waiting threads, queueing and the like to avoid missing notifications.  It's not trivial:(

Comment: @MartinJames I wanted something complex to work with. I guess I'll put this on hold for now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can:

- either rely on existing system calls that will push you notifications on file system modifications (eg: inotify)
- implement your own kernel module that will intercept file system modification and notify you (if you really want to reimplement the wheel)
- use a polling-approach, rebuild the filesystem tree in-memory and compare it every second or so. This will be very cpu/io/memory consuming, but it can be instructive.